# Handling unpaid wages

Tags: compensation

At my current job wages are paid bi-weekly, except for this month where the wages should have been paid on the 1st, but yet here we are and they are unpaid. Im wondering what is the best way to handle this situation and inquire as to whats going on with them? To clarify, Im not asking for legal advice, more on how to approach management about this.

Comment: If it isn't just you, start job hunting. A company that can't make payroll is dying.

Comment: Easy there @keshlam. It's a bit much to tell someone to leave if HR didn't get the payroll out on time *once*.

Comment: @lilleanthal: Perhaps, though not explaining/apologizing makes me worry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't get paid, then either there is a mistake, or the company is running out of money. If you are supposed to be paid on the 1st of July and there is no money at the 8th of July, *and* the company just hasn't paid, without any explanation, then it looks like the second case.

Getting paid is your highest priority. So you go to your manager, tell him that you haven't been paid, and to sort it out. If there was a mistake, then the manager will make that his highest priority and sort it out. If he doesn't make it his highest priority then you worry :-(

In that case it is still *your* highest priority. Getting paid is higher priority than following orders from your manager or doing work for customers. So next you would go to HR. If *they* don't act then you should really worry. You should proceed until (a) someone sorts out the problem that they have, or (b) someone admits they cannot pay or (c) you don't get anywhere.

In case (b) there should be an explanation, and then it is a judgement call on your side how you proceed. The company will be in financial difficulty, and you decide how big the risk is. Probably best to start job hunting, and if you are not paid, job hunting has highest priority. Boss complains you are on a job website? Tell him you haven't been paid. Boss doesn't want to give you a day off for an interview? Tell him you haven't been paid.

If you don't get anywhere, you go the legal route. Small claims court or whatever is appropriate; get proper advice elsewhere. And the job hunting starts as well.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a payroll department I would  consult with them. It's possible they would know if it is just you or a problem with the whole company as well as when it should be resolved.